# Mongoose `Undefined type at` with nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, electron

I have an application in Electron that I import mongoose and create my schemas just like anyone else. Standard stuff. I get an error if I refresh the view within Electron. It loads correctly the first time but, during development I may change something and refresh to continue but, once this error kicks in, I have to restart the application.

I'm getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Undefined type 'undefined' at 'thisfield'` error and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. The part it's referencing in the error is this:

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose' )
const schema = mongoose.Schema( {
  name: String,
  thisfield: {
    reference: String,
    unit: String,
    value: Number
  },
```

I changed field names but this field gets that error and I have no idea why. According to the Mongoose documentation, it is perfectly valid to assign a key a nest value with further key/value pairs in a schema (see the example under Defining Your Schema on the Schemas page of the documentation).

Am I missing something? Is there something within Electron or refreshing an Electron renderer that would cause this that I'm unaware of?

Comment: mongoose.Schema is a constructor, you need to prefix the `new` keyword in front of it, `new mongoose.Schema`. Your code snippet is missing a curly brace & parentheses  ? & are you initializing your model with `mongoose.model`?

Comment: I didn't include the entire schema because it was erroring from that line. That's why the curly and paren are missing. Indeed I had missed the "new" keyword on it but that doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Yes I am initializing it with `mongoose.model`

Comment: So, what it SEEMS like is that, when it opens curlys to denote the nested object, it seems like it's expecting that to be a type definition instead and doesn't recognize it as a nested object. So, when it sees the curlys, it's expecting to find the `type`, `default`, `required`, etc properties like I'm defining a type is what it seems like to me. Saying `type` is undefined makes me think that, that's what it's looking for.